# How can I make all vsplitted window as tab window?

Tags: vim, editor

How can I make all vsplitted window as tab window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do CTRL-W then T
or `:wincmd T`.

From the documentation:

```
                        *CTRL-W_T*
CTRL-W T    Move the current window to a new tab page.  This fails if
        there is only one window in the current tab page.
        When a count is specified the new tab page will be opened
        before the tab page with this index.  Otherwise it comes after
        the current tab page.
```

Note that `:windo winc T` does not work because `windo` will work only if you stay in the same tab. You can however do `:windo wincmd T | tabprevious`. (Thanks to Randy Morris for this).

Comment: No, there are three or more windows as vsplited, now what to do to make all as tab window, C-W T makes only the current window as tab.

Comment: You could do `:windo wincmd T | tabp` instead of the macro.

Comment: @Randy Morris: thanks, I had misread the documentation of windo (can't instead of can). Updating answer!